# Spring's "cloud" profile is not being recognised for standalone rabbit app

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a standalone spring / rabbit app with the following config:

```
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" reply-timeout="1000"/>

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<beans profile="cloud">
    <cloud:rabbit-connection-factory id="connectionFactory"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="default">
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"/>
</beans>
```

I have a rabbit service bound to my app correctly.

When I directly put the following in the file it works ok:

```
<cloud:rabbit-connection-factory id="connectionFactory"/>
```

In trying the use the profiles the connection is refused. Any ideas as to why the profile isn't working? All the docs seems to suggest that the profile should be automagically activated.

Comment: I am using spring 3.1 where profiles are supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spring auto-reconfiguration support only works when the application is pushed with the application type "Spring". When pushed as a Standalone app (or JavaWeb, or anything else besides Spring), then Spring auto-reconfiguration is not done.

If all you want to do is to activate the cloud profile in a stand-alone app, you can add `-Dspring.profiles.active="cloud"` to the command-line you specify when you push the app to CF.

If you need to do more complex configuration, another option would be to use [Spring Java Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-basic-concepts) and the [CloudFoundry Java Runtime API](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java/tree/master/cloudfoundry-runtime). In a `@Bean` method in a Spring `@Configuration` class, you can call the `isCloudFoundry()` method of the `CloudEnvironment` class (contained in the CF Runtime API) to detect whether the app is running on CloudFoundry or not. Based on this, you could instantiate the RabbitMQ beans appropriately.