# Information needed about the version of Cloudfoundry's tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cloud-foundry

I noticed that Cloudfoundry is using the **6.0.35** version of Tomcat by default.

I need the latest version of Tomcat (**7.0.34**) in order to be able to use **Spring MVC 3.2 async support**.

Can anyone please tell me when tomcat 7.0.34 will be available by default on cloudfoundry?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know when Tomcat 7 will be available on CloudFoundry, but in the meantime you can bundle Tomcat 7 with your application and deploy it as a stand-alone application. There is an excellent blog post about doing exactly this here: http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/06/18/deploying-tomcat-7-using-the-standalone-framework/.

Note that, if you do this, CloudFoundry will not automatically configure your app as a Spring app, since the "standalone" framework option does not do auto-reconfig. An answer to a previous question has the solution for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13632618/1299533.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I had read about this solution already. I will consider resorting to it only if CF does not plan on supporting Tomcat 7 out of the box in the future.

Comment: I've asked the CF directly and will post the reply here if and when I get one.

Comment: Hey, balteo, you again :)  You may be interested in https://github.com/ericbottard/cloudfoundry-tomcat-7